# docker redis running out of memory with magento 2

Tags: magento2, redis

My docker redis instance is running out of memory constantly and my website drops with the message that redis is loading the dataset in memory

I have set up my docker container with max 10GB and in redis.conf I added

```
maxmemory 6gb
lazyfree-lazy-eviction yes
lazyfree-lazy-expire yes
lazyfree-lazy-server-del yes
replica-lazy-flush yes
lazyfree-lazy-user-del yes
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

So I would assume that the data should get evicted when maxmemory is reached.

However, the container shows 10GB / 10GB memory used, and it's constantly failing after a couple of days.

This only happens to my magento2 website.

Comment: Additional DB information request to find extensive RAM requests, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.